# Coverting IAsyncEnumerable to ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a number of helper functions in my Xamarin app that converts from a `List` or `IList` or `IEnumerable` to an observable collecction. They all work and are all very simple

```
    public static ObservableCollection<T> ToObservable<T>(this List<T> collection) => new ObservableCollection<T>(collection as IEnumerable<T>);

    public static ObservableCollection<T> ToObservable<T>(this IList<T> collection) => new ObservableCollection<T>(collection);

    public static ObservableCollection<T> ToObservable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> original) => new ObservableCollection<T>(original);
```

The problem is that they're slow on large collections which is slowing up the app so I'm looking to create an `IAsyncEnumerable` helper. The issue though is the `IAyncEnumberable` doesn't implemt an iterator so I can't create the `ObserrvableCollection` using a `foreach` loop or directly as I did for the other helper methods

Comment: In what way to you expect async to help here?

Comment: Means the app can carry on without having to stop to convert to the ObservableCollection

Comment: So you just want to keep the UI responsive and allow the collection to be created in the background?

Comment: Pretty much, yes

Comment: Then just offload to the threadpool: `var observable = await Task.Run(collection.ToObservable);` That's assuming `collection` isn't an asynchronous iterator.

Comment: Using `await` will free the UI thread until the `ObservableCollection` is instantiated.

Comment: Thanks - great help :)

Comment: If you are here as me looking for how to convert `IAsyncEnumerable` to `IObservable` using `ToObservable` method, use the nuget package `System.Linq.Async`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wrap your function call in [`Task.Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=net-5.0) to queue the work to a thread pool thread:

```
var myObservable = await Task.Run(() => myCollection.ToObservable());
```

This should free up your UI thread and keep the UI responsive.